# Not able to change the value of a variable inside the $ajax success

Tags: variables, jquery

I am having a curiously weird problem, here is my JS code

```
function ValidateUser(username) {
   var userExists = "somevalue";


   $.ajax({
       contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Controller/Validate",
       data: JSON.stringify({ username: username }),
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",

       success: function (response) {
           alert(response);

           if (response == true) {
               userExists = true;
               alert("user exists: " + userExists);
           } else {
               alert("user exists: " + userExists);
           }
       },

       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('error');
       }

   });

    return userExists;

}
```

well, the action works fine and validates user correctly, but the function ALWAYS returns "somevalue".....What gives? My hunch is that it has something to do with a function scope. But how do I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the function you're calling `$.ajax` from returns before the Ajax call completes.

The simple answer is to do the work you need to do in the `success` function, either with an immediate function (as now), or by setting `success` to an existing function.

You could also use [jQuery's `$.when` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Comment: @sarsnake Create the function. Use it as the `success` value. Ninja edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setting "asynch: false" too, it will lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. Here is your code changed:

```
function ValidateUser(username) {
   var userExists = "somevalue";


   $.ajax({
       contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
       type: "POST",
       url: "/Controller/Validate",
       asynch: false,
       data: JSON.stringify({ username: username }),
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",

       success: function (response) {
           alert(response);

           if (response == true) {
               userExists = true;
               alert("user exists: " + userExists);
           } else {
               alert("user exists: " + userExists);
           }
       },

       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert('error');
       }

   });

    return userExists;

}
```

You can get more information here: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)